# Java Image get desktop image and create macro

Tags: java, image, macros, image-recognition

Well I'm playing a online flash game and you have to click on white boxes as fast as possible. How could I automate this with Java?  The location of boxes is randomized.

I tried using `Robot` class and use `getPixelColor`, but that is way too slow.

So what I need to do:

1. my game windows is 500x500 window, so get pixels from it
2. find 5x5 white boxes
3. click on them

Any suggestions?

Comment: "Any suggestions?"  Find better pursuits than cheating at on-line games?

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : it just a little random online game, my score doesn't really matter there, the reason why i want to do this, is to learn about image recognition with java. i mean...im not doin this to get BIG score and wow im so cool, becase its just random game and i dont care. im doin this to learn JAVA

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Rectangle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html) class, using the "contains" method.

Or you could create your own, which essentially works like this:

1. Keep track of your boxes, their current (x, y) position, and their (width, height)
2. Use the mouseClicked() event to get the (x, y) position of the click
3. Inside of mouseClicked(), loop through all your boxes, and check to see if the mouse click (x, y) is inside the box

For example if you have two boxes on the screen:

```
boxA: (x, y, width, height) = (0, 0, 10, 10)
boxB: (x, y, width, height) = (20, 20, 10, 10)
```

This gives you two boxes, each of which is 10x10 pixels in size. "boxA" has it's top-left corner at (0, 0), and "boxB" has its top-left corner at (20, 20).

If the "mouseClicked" event's (x, y) coordinate is (7, 7), then that is within the bounds of "boxA" (because the point (7, 7) is between (0, 0) and (10, 10)

If the "mouseClicked" event's (x, y) coordinate is (23, 25), then it's within "boxB", because (23, 25) is between (20, 20) and (30, 30)

You're right that getPixelColor is too slow for what you're trying to do. Looping over the list of the boxes will be **much** faster.

---

If you want to dig into a much deeper example, here's an article on the concept of [collision detection](http://beginwithjava.blogspot.com/2010/08/simple-collision-detection-in-java.html).

Comment: @normalocity : wait what? the problem is that the location of the boxes is random..so i have to go through all pixels to find it? or i am misunderstanding something? please explain

Comment: @Jaanus you don't loop through the pixels, but you keep references to the Rectangle's you paint and use http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Rectangle.html#contains(int, int) to see whether the clicked point is in there.

Comment: @Jaanus - extraneon is correct - you just loop through the rectangles, not the pixels. I also added a link at the end of my answer to an article on collision detection, which may illuminate this a little more for you.

Comment: @normalocity @extraneon : im not sure about drawing any rectangles. im playing FLASH game. and its a online game .. and i want my java program to play it for me..like a macro. can i still use your answer? i skimmed through the links, but it seems something totally different

Comment: Oh, wait - you're just trying to automate the clicks of the boxes? Wow - I completely missed that. All Java programs run in a sandbox, protecting them from accessing information about the system outside themselves (such as what's on the screen in another, completely separate program). The only way I know around this is to use C/C++ code through JNI (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), but that makes your issue a lot more complicated because you'll need to either find a code library that does this, or write your own.

Comment: @normalocity : well that would be too difficult to attach my program to that thing and try to get information out of it. thats why i am asking about image recognition..or finding pixels with java. so it would not be attaching my java program to the flash, but it would be like manual thing that just searches for pixel or smthin like that. umm..yeah and the main thing is , that i wanna do this in java...i dont wanna do any advances stuff like c++, something easy with java, but faster than robot class.

Comment: I think you're totally out of luck on this one. Because of the way Java is setup, it won't let you do this kind of stuff easily, by design.

Comment: @normalocity : i read something a about BufferedImage http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html .. im not sure how to use it..  do you know smthin about this? may this help me?

Comment: BufferedImages are used to store image data, but it won't do what you're hoping. I used them a lot in my game development.

Comment: You need some way to get data from the OS through the Win32 API. This looks like it's designed to do precisely that, and may not require writing C/C++ code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525900/java-win32-libraries-api

Comment: @normalocity : damn..i really hoped someone had made a java package or something for faster image-recognition..