# What is the best way to determine the number of GDI objects within a Java program?

Tags: java, windows

We had the task to periodically check the number of GDI objects a Java process is using on a Windows machine. We had a leak issue leak issue using some third party library. When a certain limit is reached, the application more or less crashes. You can see them in the Windows task manager when you add the GDI-Objects column.

Since we didn't find an existing method we ended up using [JNA-Platform-library](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/tree/master/dist) to get access to the [GetGuiResources API function](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getguiresources) of the user32.dll.

We did the following:

1. extended User32-interface and added a corresponding method
2. created an INSTANCE of the extended interface using Native.loadLibrary()
3. called the method of the INSTANCE by using Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcess() and DWORD(0)

The code now looks like this:

```
public class GdiTester { 

    private static interface ExtendedUser32 extends User32 {
        /** 
         * Provides access to the user32.dll-API-Function GetGuiResources.
         * 
         * @param hProcess the process
         * @param uiFlags flags (e.g. 0 to get the number of GDI-objects)
         * @return result of the API-function call (e.g. the number of GDI-objects)
         */
        DWORD GetGuiResources(HANDLE hProcess, DWORD uiFlags);
    }

    private static ExtendedUser32 INSTANCE = Native.loadLibrary("user32", ExtendedUser32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Number of GDI-objects: " + INSTANCE.GetGuiResources(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetCurrentProcess(), new DWORD(0)).intValue());
    }
}
```

Do you know an other (better) way to do this?